# Merge Several Picture Box Image and Save

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I currently work on image processing application. I have 'Main' PictureBox as canvas. I want to insert some PictureBox into 'Main' PictureBox and merge all as one Image then save it to png. This is my code. Can anybody help me to acccomplish this task please?

```
        Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(pictureEdit.Width, pictureEdit.Height);
        bmp = (Bitmap)pictureEdit.Image;

        foreach (Control c in pictureEdit.Controls)
        {
            if (c is Functions.pictureEdit)
            {
                using (var bitmap = new Bitmap(pictureEdit.Image.Width, pictureEdit.Image.Height)) {
                    using (var canvas = Graphics.FromImage(bitmap)) {
                        canvas.DrawImage(bmp, new Rectangle(0, 0, pictureEdit.Image.Width, pictureEdit.Image.Height));
                        canvas.DrawImage(((Functions.pictureEdit)c).img, new Rectangle(0, 0, pictureEdit.Image.Width, pictureEdit.Image.Height));
                        canvas.Save();
                    }
                    bitmap.Save(@"D:\Test\new.png", System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope you are okay with Combining images together
Following code does that

private Bitmap CombineBitmap(List lstImages, int width, int height)

{

```
       int iTilesPerWidth = 5; 
        //create a bitmap to hold the combined image
        Bitmap finalImage = new System.Drawing.Bitmap(width, height);
        //get a graphics object from the image so we can draw on it
        using (System.Drawing.Graphics g = System.Drawing.Graphics.FromImage(finalImage))
        {
            PointF point1 = new PointF(0, 0);
            int nCount = 1;
            foreach (Bitmap BM in lstImages)
            {
                //512, 256
                g.DrawImage(BM, point1);
                point1.X += BM.Width;
                if (nCount % iTilesPerWidth == 0)
                {
                    point1.X = 0;
                    point1.Y += BM.Height;
                }
                nCount++;
            }

        }
        return finalImage;
    }
```